# IF-THEN-ELSE with calling a function

Tags: vba, ms-access

I wrote that if-else clause but its not working correct and i dont know why. 
As you can see i want to check if a mail was already sent.

```
If informiert2 = True Then

    If MsgBox("Weitere Benachrichtigung versenden?", vbOKCancel, "Kunde bereits informiert") = vbOK Then

        MsgBox "Test"
        Call sendemailKunde

    End If

Else

    Call sendemailKunde

End If
```

In case the mail was already sent, i want to have a popup which asks if you want to send the mail again. If you click on `yes` nothing happens instead of the `MsgBox "Test"` but the function `sendemailKunde` wont be called.

In case the mail wasnt sent already, the function is called properly and works fine.

Comment: it should work, what do you have inside your `sendemailKunde` code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Gustav, looks good. If you do not want to update the variable informiert2 i.e. its being used afterwards too, then you can use below code.

```
Dim NeedToSendEmail As Boolean
If informiert2 Then
    If MsgBox("Weitere Benachrichtigung versenden?", vbOKCancel, "Kunde bereits informiert") = vbOK Then
        NeedToSendEmail = True
    End If
Else
    NeedToSendEmail = True
End If

If NeedToSendEmail Then
    Call sendemailKunde
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle the code a little:

```
If informiert2 = True Then
    If MsgBox("Weitere Benachrichtigung versenden?", vbOKCancel, "Kunde bereits informiert") = vbOK Then
        informiert2 = False
    End If
End If
If informiert2 = False Then
    Call sendemailKunde
End If
```